# How to save objects from one database to a table in another Flask SQLAlchemy SQLlite

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am working on a project in which people can search books with ratings. The site has a login form which leads to a dashboard. I am wondering how to add books to a "saved books" list on the dashboard. I am using a SQLite Database so an array is not an option. Any suggestions for how to save books to a saved books table for each user would be greatly appreciated.

My User Model:

```
class User(UserMixin, userDB.Model):
    id = userDB.Column(userDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = userDB.Column(userDB.Text(30), unique =True)
    password = userDB.Column(userDB.Text(30))
```

My book model:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"


    title = Column(Text)
    price = Column('price', Integer)
    img = Column('image', String)
    rating = Column('rating', String)
    id = Column('id', String,primary_key=True,)
```

Comment: Have a read up on relationships - [SQLAlchemy Basic Relationship Patterns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table "savedbooks", for example, in the same database with columns: id(primary key autoincrement), id_user(foreing key user) and id_book(foreing key id in books).
After you can retrieve the saved books by id of the user in "savedbooks" table.